# How to fetch data from sql databse when it changes and updatde to div without reloading page

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax

I'm making a simple comment and reply to comment page. I've some code that can post comment and display with ajax, but when I open same page in two browser it works in one browser and in second browser's div it doesn't update comment. My problem is I want if I post from one browser I want another browser also update div.
My index.php file is like below:

```
<?php 
     include('config.php');
     $to = 1;
       $from = 1;
     $pak = 1;
?>
 <html>
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="process.js"></script>
      </head>
          <body>
         <div id="responds"></div>
                            <form action="process.php" method="post" name="content_txt" id="contentd">
                                <input name="from" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $from; ?>" id="from">
                                <input name="to" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $to; ?>" id="to">
                                <input name="pak" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pak; ?>" id="pak">
                                <textarea id="john" placeholder="whats on your mind ?" name="content"></textarea><br>
                            <div id="button" style="width:100%;height:33px;font-family:tahoma;">
                                <div id="update_button">
                                    <input type="submit" value="POST" style="padding:5px;" class="uupdate"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </form> 
                          <img src="loading.gif" id="LoadingImage" style="display:none" />
                        </body>
                </html>
```

and process.js file is below

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

  //##### send add record Ajax request to process.php #########
   $(".uupdate").click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        if($("#john").val()==='')
        {
            alert("Please enter some text!");
            return false;
        }

        $(".uupdate").hide(); //hide submit button
        $("#LoadingImage").show(); //show loading image

        var to = document.getElementById("to").value;
        var from = document.getElementById("from").value;
        var pak = document.getElementById("pak").value;
        var content = document.getElementById("john").value;

        var myData = 'to=' + to + '&from=' + from + '&pak=' + pak + '&content=' + content;

        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "process.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:myData, //Form variables
        success:function(response){
            $("#responds").append(response);
            $("#john").val(''); //empty text field on successful
            $(".uupdate").show(); //show submit button
            $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image

        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            $(".uupdate").show(); //show submit button
            $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image
            alert(thrownError);
        }
        });

     });
     });
```

and process.php file is

```
<?php 
    include('config.php');
    if(isset($_POST["content"]) && strlen($_POST["content"])>0) 
    {
        $to = $_POST['to'];
        $from = $_POST['from'];
        $pak = $_POST['pak'];
        $content = htmlspecialchars($_POST['content']);
        $time=time();
        $john = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO status(eto, content, efrom, pak, created)VALUES('$to', '$content', '$from', '$pak', '$time')");
            if($john) {
        $my_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
            echo '<div id="item_'.$my_id.'">';
            echo '<form class="rep_wrapper" method="post" action="reply.php"><input type="text" class="rep_box" id="rep-'.$my_id.'">';
            echo '</form>';
            echo $content;
            echo '</div>';
            $mysqli->close(); //close db connection

            }else{

            header('HTTP/1.1 500 Looks like mysql error, could not insert record!');
            exit();
        }

    }
   ?>
```

this works fine in single browser but doesn't update 
       `<div id="responds"></div>` on second browser.

but when I added following code on index.php

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
           var auto_refresh = setInterval(
              function ()
                    {
                $('#responds').load('check.php').fadeIn("slow");
                    }, 1000);
     </script>
```

this code works on both browser but 
 it doesn't let me type reply on

```
  <input type="text" class="rep_box" id="rep-'.$my_id.'">
```

because that js reloads my div every second.
How I can fix this problem?
Anyone please answer.

Comment: You either need to use websocket or long pulling to achieve this. Since a lot of browser support websocket these days that's an viable option. Here is where you can learn about websocket https://www.websocket.org/echo.html. But you have clients with older browser ajax long pulling could be a good option

Comment: thaks #qamar let me check first and reply. thanks for reply

Comment: @qamar you should post this as an answer